# Can I create a new GATT characteristic on a BLE peripheral remotely from a central?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Is it possible to create a new GATT service/characteristic at runtime on a peripheral device from a central device?
When a peripheral device comes near a central, I am trying to store an id onto the peripheral device so that I can recognize the device later when it connects to a different central.

I have tried connecting/pairing with the peripheral devices and I am able to read/write GATT characteristics that are already defined on the device. Is it possible to do the same for ones that are not defined on the peripheral?

As I can understand, these services/characteristics have to be defined by the peripheral (GATT server) so that any GATT client can access them, so what I am trying to achieve may not be possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In any case, you can always modify the GATT db if you notify the client of the changes using the Service Changed Characteristic Indication.

Comment: Why would you need a new characteristic for that? Couldn't you use an existing one that's storing a default value at the beginning?

Comment: I do not have access to the peripheral device so I cannot make any changes there. I was wondering if it was possible for a client to modify the GATT db on the peripheral's GATT server so that I can add new characteristics.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.